# Mysql CLuster : disk space not freed after deleting rows

Tags: mysql

I have deleted all the rows in mysql cluster tables having disk data tables.It still shows used extents ....??? How can i free those used extents.... If i use truncate table than only the extents are freed else they are still occupied after deleting rows using DELETE statement

Comment: If you are using InnoDB, then mysql never cleans .idb file. You need to use innodb_file_per_table.

Comment: I am using ndb engine

Answer (score 0):

The space should be reused when you add new rows to the table

Comment: yes but i cannot add rows to new table ..... only in that table i can add more rows in which i have deleted rows ... !!!